# Apache Spark: Get number of records per partition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

I want to check how can we get information about each partition such as total no. of records in each partition on driver side when Spark job is submitted with deploy mode as a yarn cluster in order to log or print on the console.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can get the number of records per partition like this :

```
df
  .rdd
  .mapPartitionsWithIndex{case (i,rows) => Iterator((i,rows.size))}
  .toDF("partition_number","number_of_records")
  .show
```

But this will also launch a Spark Job by itself (because the file must be read by spark to get the number of records).

Spark could may also read hive table statistics, but I don't know how to display those metadata..

Answer (score 35):

I'd use built-in function. It should be as efficient as it gets:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.spark_partition_id

df.groupBy(spark_partition_id).count
```

Comment: You can use `df.withColumn("partition_id", spark_partition_id).groupBy("partition_id").count` for 1.6

Answer (score 27):

For future PySpark users:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions  import spark_partition_id
rawDf.withColumn("partitionId", spark_partition_id()).groupBy("partitionId").count().show()
```

Answer (score 5):

Spark/scala:

```
val numPartitions = 20000
val a = sc.parallelize(0 until 1e6.toInt, numPartitions )
val l = a.glom().map(_.length).collect()  # get length of each partition
print(l.min, l.max, l.sum/l.length, l.length)  # check if skewed
```

PySpark:

```
num_partitions = 20000
a = sc.parallelize(range(int(1e6)), num_partitions)
l = a.glom().map(len).collect()  # get length of each partition
print(min(l), max(l), sum(l)/len(l), len(l))  # check if skewed
```

The same is possible for a `dataframe`, not just for an `RDD`. 
Just add `DF.rdd.glom`... into the code above.

Credits: Mike Dusenberry @ https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17817

Answer (score 3):

#### Spark 1.5  solution :

(`sparkPartitionId()` exists in `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 

df.withColumn("partitionId", sparkPartitionId()).groupBy("partitionId").count.show
```

as mentioned by @Raphael Roth

`mapPartitionsWithIndex` is best approach, will work with all version of spark since its RDD based approach

Answer (score 0):

PySpark:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import spark_partition_id

df.select(spark_partition_id().alias("partitionId")).groupBy("partitionId").count()
```