# Spark distribute tasks over several executors

Tags: apache-spark

I d'like to run a SQL query in parallel and be able to control the level of parallelism to 8 queries. Right now, I am doing this piece of code.
The idea is to create 8 partition and allow executors to run them in parallel.

```scala
  (1 to 8).toSeq.toDF.repartition(8) // 8 partitions
  .rdd.mapPartitions(
  x => {
  val conn = createConnection()
    x.foreach{
      s => { // expect the below query be run concurently
      execute(s"SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE col = ${s.get(0)}")
      }
    }
  conn.close()
  x
  }).take(1)
```

The problem is the 8 queries are run one by one.

How should I proceed to get queries run 8 by 8 ?

Comment: It should be okay if you are having enough resources to run 8 jobs in parallel (at least 8 threads in executors). You can also try executing the sql using udf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do

```scala
val df = (1 to 8).toSeq.toDF.repartition(8)
```

This will not create 8 partitions with 1 record each. If you inspect this dataframe (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46032600/1138523), then you get :

```
+----------------+-----------------+
|partition_number|number_of_records|
+----------------+-----------------+
|               0|                0|
|               1|                0|
|               2|                0|
|               3|                0|
|               4|                0|
|               5|                0|
|               6|                4|
|               7|                4|
+----------------+-----------------+
```

So you will have only 2 partitions which are non empty, therefore you will have at max 2-fold parallelism (I've asked about this here : [How does Round Robin partitioning in Spark work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54123887/how-does-round-robin-partitioning-in-spark-work))

To make equal-sized partitions, you better use

```
spark.sparkContext.parallelize((0 to 7), numSlices = 8)
```

instead of

```
(1 to 8).toSeq.toDF.repartition(8).rdd
```

The first option gives you 1 record per partition, the second one not as it uses round robin partitioning

As a side note, when you do `x.foreach`, then `x` will be consumed (Iterators are only traversable once) so if you return `x` you will always get an empty iterator.

So your final code can look like this :

```scala
 spark.sparkContext.parallelize((0 to 7), numSlices = 8)
.mapPartitions(
  x => {
  val xL = x.toList  // convert to List
  assert(xL.size==1) // make sure partition has only 1 record

  val conn = createConnection()
    xL.foreach{
      s => { // expect the below query be run concurently
      execute(s"SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE col = ${s}")
      }
    }
  conn.close()
  xL.toIterator
  })
 .collect // trigger all queries
```

Instead of using `mapPartitions` (which is lazy), you could also use `foreachPartition`, which is non-lazy

As you have only 1 record per partition, iterating the partitions isn't really beneficial, you could also just use a plain `foreach`:

```scala
 spark.sparkContext.parallelize((0 to 7), numSlices = 8)
.foreach( s=> {
  val conn = createConnection()
  execute(s"SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE col = ${s}")   
  conn.close()
})
```

Comment: can you please tell a bit what would be the benefit of using foreachPartition over mapPartitions ?

Comment: Your method has been working when I use *ForeachPartition* only.

Comment: @parisni are you sure you tried `mapPartitions` followed by `collect`?  `count` should also do the trick if you don't need the return values

Comment: I mean *mapPartitions* works. It just didn't distribute as well as foreachPartition. Maybe related to lazy aspects

Comment: I was using take(1), maybe that makes sense and I should have test with collect. Anyway thanks for your help.