# Spark dataset withColumn add partition id

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset, hadoop-partitioning

### I am trying to write a helper function that takes a dataset of any type`Dataset[_]`, and returns with one new column "partitionId" which is the id of the partition that single data unit belongs to.

For example, if I have a dataset below and by default it has two partitions.

```
+-----+------+
| colA|  colB|
+-----+------+
|   1 |     a|
|   2 |     b|
|   3 |     c|
+-----+------+
```

After the function, it should be the the result below, where the first two data units belong to the same partition and the third one belongs to another partition.

```
+-----+------+------------+
| colA|  colB| partitionId|
+-----+------+------------+
|   1 |     a|           1|
|   2 |     b|           1|
|   3 |     c|           2|
+-----+------+------------+
```

I tried with withColumn() and mapPartitions(), but none of them worked for me.
For withColumn(), I couldn't get the the info of what partition the data unit belongs to, like `withColumn("partitionId", {What should be here to add the partitionId?})`
For mapPartitions(), I tried:

```scala
dataset
  .mapPartitions(iter => {
    val partitionId = UUID.randomUUID().toString
    iter.map(dataUnit => MyDataType.addPartitionId(partitionId))
  })
```

But this only works for specific type like `Dataset[MyDataType]`, not for `Dataset[_]`

How can I add a partitionId column for any dataset?

Comment: if you remove the groupby in the above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032320/apache-spark-get-number-of-records-per-partition) then you will print all the recurring partition with their number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there a reason you need the partition ID of each record? Either way, you can achieve it by:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.spark_partition_id
...
dataFrame.withColumn("partitionID", spark_partition_id)
```

Comment: it should be this way: dataFrame.withColumn("partitionID", spark_partition_id())

Comment: You don't have to use empty parentheses while using Scala.

Comment: How will we make this work in Java