# Spark job getting stuck in local mode

Tags: apache-spark

I am facing an issue where my spark jobs are getting stuck in local while running in IntelliJ idea. My jobs run till a stage like Completing 199 of 200 jobs or completing 1 of 3 tasks and gets stuck there.

I tried to see what is happening using evaluate expression in my IDE and noticed a weird problem. If I am using myDf.rdd.map(r => r).cache() I get

```
java.io.IOException: Class not found
at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getInnerClosureClasses(ClosureCleaner.scala:81)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2067)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.map(DataFrame.scala:1410)
at com.marin.jobcoordinator.spark.extractor.PoExtractorBase$GeneratedEvaluatorClass$18$1.invoke(FileToCompile.scala:66)
```

At the same time, if I use myDf.rdd.collect I am not seeing this issue. I am able to invoke myDf.show without any problems as well. It is just that when I use map function with anonymous identity function, I am facing this problem. From the exception, what I am getting is that spark is trying to load the class of anonymous function and erroring out?? Seems very strange.

I am using spark version 1.6.0

Thanks,

Sriram

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I gave the simplistic version of the code. Looks like it is more to do with IntelliJ idea classloading while working with spark programs. I am able to reproduce the same issue in my other projects under similar invocation.

Comment: @sriram did you figure it out?

Comment: @IonFreeman I haven't resolved that. I just resorted to building the jar and running it in cluster instead of trying to debug this issue from local - as identifying the root cause of this issue just seems to take forever for me.

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem, completing 199 tasks and then getting stuck on the last one, well most of the time this is a skew problem: your data is badly partitioned. Computing [the number of elements for each partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28687149/how-to-get-the-number-of-elements-in-partition) and printing it before doing your suspicious operation might give you a hint. Repartitioning and filtering (if possible) your data beforehand can help.

Also using 200 partitions means that you (most likely) use the **default** number of partitions when data are shuffled. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704156/what-is-the-difference-between-spark-sql-shuffle-partitions-and-spark-default-pa) for more info. You can try changing that to fit the number of cores you have on your machine.

For your second problem, I can't help you, sorry.

Comment: This is the likely scenario and should be the accepted answer